# Value overflows specified precision 0 with scale 0

Tags: java, apache-drill

I'm trying to create custom fuction for Apache Drill (v1.15).

When using a Decimal as an **output** data type, it fails even with the simplest example. 
When using another data types (int, float ..), it works well.

Is there any simple way, how to make decimals work as output of UDF?

```java
@FunctionTemplate(
        name = "testing_udf",
        scope = FunctionTemplate.FunctionScope.SIMPLE,
        nulls = FunctionTemplate.NullHandling.NULL_IF_NULL
)
public class TestingUdfFunction implements DrillSimpleFunc {

    @Param
        Decimal18Holder input;
    @Output
        Decimal18Holder out;

    public void setup() {
    }

    public void eval() {
        out.precision = input.precision;
        out.scale = input.scale;
        out.value = input.value;
    }
}
```

SQL Call:

```sql
SELECT testing_udf(6.66);
> VALIDATION ERROR: Value 7 overflows specified precision 0 with scale 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

UDFs which return decimal data type should also specify `returnType` in `@FunctionTemplate` to be able to determine resulting scale and precision. You can use functions implementations from `VarDecimalFunctions` class as an example.