# No match found for function signature when NullHandling set to INTERNAL

Tags: apache-drill

I'm trying to implement an user defined function for Apache Drill.

The function takes float arguments ([decimals do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56872634/value-overflows-specified-precision-0-with-scale-0)) and they have to be nullable in order to return zeroes.

However, when I use `NullHandling.Internal` and set the parameters as nullable types, the function can be no longer invoked.

```sql
SELECT tetsting_udf(1.23,4.56);
```

> VALIDATION ERROR: (...): No match found for function signature TESTING_UDF(<DECIMAL>, <DECIMAL>)

```sql
SELECT tetsting_udf(cast(1.23 as float), cast(4.56 as float));
```

> VALIDATION ERROR: (...): No match found for function signature TESTING_UDF(<FLOAT>, <FLOAT>)

When Float8Holders and NullHandling.NULL_IF_NULL is used, both calls above are working.

What I'm doing wrong?

```java
@FunctionTemplate(
        name = "testing_udf",
        scope = FunctionTemplate.FunctionScope.SIMPLE,
        nulls = FunctionTemplate.NullHandling.INTERNAL
)
public class TestingFunction implements DrillSimpleFunc {

     @Param
         NullableFloat8Holder numberA;
     @Param
         NullableFloat8Holder numberB;
     @Output

     Float8Holder out;

     public void setup() {
     }

     public void eval() {
         // Whatever
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case when `FunctionTemplate.NullHandling.INTERNAL` is specified, UDFs implementations with all combinations of nullability should be specified. For your case, you should specify UDFs which accepts (`Float8Holder` and `Float8Holder`), (`NullableFloat8Holder` and `NullableFloat8Holder`), (`Float8Holder` and `NullableFloat8Holder`), (`NullableFloat8Holder` and `Float8Holder`).